# $ 2g(z)=g(\frac{z}{2}) + g(\frac{z+1}{2})$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let g be an entire function such that

$2g(z)=g(\frac{z}{2}) + g(\frac{z+1}{2})$ holds $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$

the I want to prove that $ g $ is constant.

Hint: Apply maximum modulus principle on $cl(B_r (0))=${$ |z| \leq r $}$ $

also

if $g$ has no zeros and  $cg(z)=g(\frac{z}{2}) g(\frac{z+1}{2})$  holds $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$ and for some $c\in \mathbb{C}$ prove that $g(z)=ce^{\frac{-b}{2}}e^{bz}$ for some $b\in \mathbb{C}$

I have no idea how to prove this statement . Any Hints leading to solutions  are appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1, we let $R$ large enough so $\frac{R+1}{2} <R$ (any $R>1$ will do) and $M=\max_{|z|=R}|g(z)|$, with $|g(w)|=M$ for some fixed $|w|=R$ by continuity. By maximum modulus $|g(\frac{w}{2})| \le M, |g(\frac{w+1}{2})| \le M$ but the hypothesis implies we must have equalities in both, so by maximum modulus again $g$ is constant.

For part 2, $c \ne 0$ since $g$ has no zeroes, so if we let $h(z)=\frac{g(z)}{c}$, $h$ also is entire with no zeroes and $h(z)=h(\frac{z}{2}) h(\frac{z+1}{2})$.

There is a holomorphic logarithm $k(z)=\log h(z)$ and if $k(z)-k(\frac{z}{2}) -k(\frac{z+1}{2})=2m(z)\pi i$ we get by exponentiation that $m(z)$ is integral for any $z$ and since $m$ is obviously a continuos function, $m$ must be a constant integer.

But now $k'(z)=\frac{1}{2}(k'(\frac{z}{2}) +k'(\frac{z+1}{2}))$ so by part 1, $k'(z)=b$ constant, hence $k(z)=bz+a$, $h(z)=e^ae^{bz}$.

Since $h(0)=e^a, h(\frac{1}{2})=e^{a+\frac{b}{2}}$ and $h(0)=h(0)h(\frac{1}{2})$, we get $e^a=e^{-\frac{b}{2}}$ so $h(z)=e^{-\frac{b}{2}}e^{bz}$ and rembering that $g(z)=ch(z)$ part 2 is done also!

(note that $e^{a+\frac{b}{2}}=1$ doesn't necessarily imply that $a+\frac{b}{2}=0$, but we need only that $e^a=e^{-\frac{b}{2}}$ which is clearly true)

Answer (score 0):

As $g(z)$ is entire we can write:

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n z^n}{n!}$$

leaving:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\frac{a^n z^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n z^n}{2^n n!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n (z+1)^n}{2^nn!}$$

Because this needs to be valid for all $z$ it has to be, if $a_n \neq 0, n>0$

$$(2^{n+1}-1) z^n - (z+1)^n = 0$$
$$ z = \frac1{(2^{n+1}-1)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1} $$

but this is contradiction to the fact that the expression must be valid for all $z$. The only option is $a_n=0, n>0$ making only $a_0$ possibly different from $0$.